# Is this the actual size of panel?

Tags: java, swing, size, jpanel, dimension

```
JPanel scorePanel = new JPanel();
scorePanel.setBackground( new Color( 95 , 8 , 248 , 255 ));
JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel( "Score : 0"  );
scoreLabel.setForeground( Color.white );
scoreLabel.setFont( new Font( "Cambria" , Font.BOLD , 20 ) );
scorePanel.add(scoreLabel);
Dimension d =new Dimension( scorePanel.getSize() );
System.out.println(d);
```

The output of this snippet when run along with the whole code is-**java.awt.Dimension[width=0,height=0]**

**Why do i get this output, when in scorepanel i have a label of size 20 ? Is** *this* **the actual size of scorepanel ?**

Comment: I get this output after packing into a container.

Comment: Even after rendering the frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, it's not**. Once it's been *realized* (i.e. packed into a container and rendered), the actual dimensions of the component will be made available.

Comment: what does `0,0` indicate ? I get this output only after packing into a container

Comment: The layout manager doesn't set the size to (0, 0), The default size and location of all components are (0, 0), when the component is created. The layout manager will determine the appropriate size and location whenever it is invoked which is basically whenever the frame is make visible or resized or a component is validated.

Comment: yes i get the result **java.awt.Dimension[width=400,height=35]**

Comment: @camickr, thanks for the clarification. I removed my misleading comment. :)

Comment: @ little bunny foo foo **what is rendering ?**

Comment: @Subhail Gupta, Once it's "visible".